# NamedNativeQuery / ConstructorResult in Spring Boot + Kotlin: Couldn't find PersistentEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to add a query method to `AlertRepository` using NamedNativeQuery / ConstructorResult.  Our Kotlin code is heavily based on this Java example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/jpa21#support-for-custom-sqlresultsetmapping-with-constructorresult

Here's what I've added to the `Alert` entity:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "hourly-alert-counts",
        classes = [
            ConstructorResult(targetClass = HourlyAlertCount::class, columns = [
                ColumnResult(name = "day", type = Int::class),
                ColumnResult(name = "hour", type = Int::class),
                ColumnResult(name = "count", type = Long::class)
            ])
        ]
)
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "Alert.getHourlyCountsByConfigurationItemId",
        query = "select {fn DAYOFWEEK(reported_time)} as day, hour(reported_time) as hour, count(*) as count from alert\n" +
                "where configuration_item = ?1 group by configuration_item, {fn DAYOFWEEK(reported_time)}, hour(reported_time)",
        resultSetMapping = "hourly-alert-counts"
)
data class Alert(
  ...
```

and to the AlertRepository:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true)
fun getHourlyCountsByConfigurationItemId(id: Long): List<HourlyAlertCount>
```

Finally, the HourlyAlertCount POJO:

```
data class HourlyAlertCount(
    val day: Int,
    val hour: Int,
    val count: Long
)
```

When I hit this endpoint, I get the following error:

```
{"cause":null,"message":"Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class xxx.HourlyAlertCount!"}
```

ConstructorResult / ColumnResult are supposed to be annotations in Java, but our Kotlin code doesn't compile if we add the "@" before them; [this blog post](https://medium.com/@tomokazukozuma/points-to-note-when-implementing-spring-boot-with-kotlin-735934b15313) suggests to ignore the "@".  We're using spring-data-jpa 2.09 and Hibernate 5.2.17.